# does dev_queue_xmit depends on dst_entry in skb

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I am working on a network module and need to **send out packet** to specific destinations (think as software router).
I want to send a `sk_buff` to some IP address, passing it to `dev_queue_xmit()`.
However, I am feeling complex with `dst_entry` concept.
Can `dev_queue_xmit` send a skb, without a valid dst_entry, when the skb has necessary `link layer` info ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, I eventually concluded that skb need not have a valid `dst_entry` for successfully transmitting a packet. All that it needs is a valid buffer, with `skb->data` pointing to correct `mac_header` location.